# Struts 2 Hello World Tutorial Gives 404

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I have been following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_examples.htm) tutorial on Struts.

This is my file structure:

[image: This is my file structure]

I thought I followed everything step by step, I did a similar tutorial earlier and was able to get it to work in another version, but I'm trying Struts 2.3.33 now. I am running this on an Apache Tomcat 8.5 server. I try to go to `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp` but it gives a 404 error message and I can't figure out why. I have also ensured that the Struts files are both in my build path and my deployment assembly as well as in my WEB-INF/lib folder.

I am getting no errors in my console, this is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My struts.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: This version doesn't work with jre 1.8

Comment: @Roman C I ran the tutorial using the OP's environment (Struts 2.3.33 and Tomcat 8.5) and it worked for me using JRE 1.8. See my updated post below.

Comment: What do you mean by OP's environment? As far as I read that tutorial it's used Struts 2.2.3 and nothing related to JRE version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed that tutorial with your environment (Eclipse + Struts 2.3.33 + Tomcat 8.5.20) and it worked on Windows 10 using Java 1.8.

Like you, I had to deviate from the tutorial by adding **commons-lang3-3.2.jar** to **WEB-INF/lib** to avoid a **NoClassDefFoundError** at runtime when using Struts 2.3.33. However, I see you also made two changes to **web.xml** that deviated from the tutorial:

- Firstly, you specified **version="2.5"** where it should be **version="3.0"**.
- Secondly, you specified     **org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter**
  instead of **org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher** for the **filter-class**.

Given that the tutorial worked fine for me without modifying their **web.xml**, I suggest you revert your two changes and try again.

What prompted you to modify their **web.xml** file?

---

**Updated response** based on the OP's comment below:

OK. One other deviation from the tutorial I just noticed is that you named your project **Struts2.3 with Tiles 2** rather than **HelloWorldStruts2**. I doubt if your project knows anything about **HelloWorldStruts2**, which would explain why you are getting a 404.

By default your context root will be **Struts2.3_with_Tiles_2**, not **HelloWorldStruts2**, so your URL needs to be changed to http://localhost:8080/Struts2.3_with_Tiles_2/index.jsp.

You can see your project's **Context Root** by selecting your project, right clicking, choosing **Properties** from the popup menu, and then selecting **Web Project Settings**. Whatever you see in the **Context Root** field is what should be specified in your URL.

So to clarify:

- What **exactly** is the context root for your project?
- What **exactly** are you specifying for the URL?

If that doesn't resolve the issue I suggest running the tutorial again, but follow their instructions precisely (apart from the specific Struts 2 files you need to copy, but you are already doing that correctly).

Comment: The reason I deviated was when I started my server, I got the 404 message after following the tutorial exactly. i had worked this tutorial earlier with another version of Struts (2.5) but found problems integrating with other plugins so I'm trying to go back and recreate this tutorial with version 2.3.33. After getting the 404 I tried to copy my web.xml from the other project but that didn't work. 

I reverted my web.xml back to the tutorial but am still getting the 404 error.

Comment: I believe you're right, I'm not at home right now but when I get on the machine that has this I'll try it. I think it was a stupid error I forgot to change when I made this project, thank you for pointing this out, I'll update and if it works accept your answer.

Comment: This was my problem, thank you for helping me realize this dumb mistake!